# Apache ignoring .htaccess rules and returning 404 not found

Tags: apache-2.2, php, centos, .htaccess

I just set up Apache and PHP on a server running CentOS by using something along the lines of `yum install httpd` and `yum install php`.

I've created the following file in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhosts.conf`:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin contact@domain.com
     ServerName dl.domain.com
     ServerAlias dl.domain.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/dl.domain.com/html
     ErrorLog /var/www/dl.domain.com/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /var/www/dl.domain.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Not that it isn't actually `domain.com`, it's the actual domain that I'm using.

Then, in `/var/www/dl.domain.com/html/.htaccess` I have the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
# RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

The problem is I'm getting 404 not found errors when accessing a URL like `http://dl.domain.com/something/somethingelse`. The requests don't seem to be going through the `index.php` script which the `.htaccess` file tells them to.

I've tried setting `RewriteBase` to `/var/www/dl.domain.com/html/` but still no luck.

I have the same thing set up on localhost for development and it works perfectly. Can anyone spot what might be going wrong here?

Comment: 1) Why not put the rewrite stuff in the apache config as well? 2) http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Answer (score 0):

Check whether there is a  directive in your Apache config and there is AllowOverride.  If should be set on All. If it is not there, add it to make sure the .htaccess file is being read.

Wishes,

[Mohammad Ali Sharpasand](http://m.a.sharpasand.com/)